# DiscordJS error : FFmpeg/avconv not found! showing up after installing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ffmpeg, discord.js

I've been installed the FFmpeg extension using npm, **and** git also, and this following error still shows itself...

```
Successfully connected.
Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
    at Function.getInfo (D:\bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:130:11)
    at Function.create (D:\bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:38)
    at new FFmpeg (D:\bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:44:27)    at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (D:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:47:20)
    at VoiceConnection.play (D:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:71:28)
    at D:\bot\index.js:36:47
```

I don't know what to do also...
I'll be happy for help ;)

Comment: Do you have the ffmpeg.exe file installed?

Comment: Yes, try going to the official ffmpeg website and following their installation instructions. Afterwards, add ffmpeg to your PATH. They may show you how to do this, but Im not 100% sure, you might need to find another tutorial if you dont know how.